# How can I install gcc 4.2.1 on OSX Sierra?

Tags: c, gcc, macos-high-sierra, bochs

I'm using the Bochs emulator and for my class we're using gcc 4.2.1. I believe I've gotten Bochs running, but now I need to compile our programs which are compatible with gcc 4.2/.1.

I understand OSX uses an alias for gcc 4.2.1, but how can I use gcc specifically and not clang?

Edit: GCC 4.6.3 not 4.2.1 sorry

Comment: GCC 4.2 was released more than a decade ago. Why on earth are you required to use such an out of date toolchain?

Comment: @acm .. it might be 'out of date', but that doesn't mean it doesn't work great as a compiler .. to wit, OpenBSD still uses 4.2.1(for many reasons).

Comment: A good point is made though .. is there a _specific_ reason you _need_ 4.2.1 versus just using what comes on the mac? That is to say, are you writing C code that uses gcc 4.2.1 compiler specific code, or is the code your writing ANSI/ISO C that could compile just as well on any other compiler? If you _need_ 4.2.1, you might need to utilize [homebrew](http://caiustheory.com/install-gcc-421-apple-build-56663-with-xcode-42/)

Comment: I agree GCC 4.2.1 was a great vintage of GCC. But I'm hard pressed to think of reasons it might be *required* for a student project.

Comment: We’re writing components of an operating system in Bochs using a virtual machine, and I thought we were using gcc was 4.2.1 but it’s actually 4.6.3, sorry. A classmate told me he compiled the projects with gcc 5.4 on the VM, but I believe my main issue is compiling Bochs itself to get it running.

Comment: Why don't you just install bochs from homebrew?

Comment: AH never mind

So I had installed Bochs from homebrew but thought it wasn't working because my project wasn't compiling. But that's just the C code not compiling. Bochs actually DOES run. I just need to compile my C code with the right compiler.

I suppose my point still stands, how would I go about compiling with GCC 4.6.3?

Comment: At least for me brew seems to have a gcc@4.9 package, but nothing older. You could always build GCC from source, but that is a chore. I still want to know why you need to use any specific version of GCC though. What happens if you build and compile your code with a newer version and try to run it in bochs? Does it work? If not, how does it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install previous version of gcc pretty easily using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

If you have homebrew installed you can get gcc 4.9 by running

```
brew install gcc@4.9
```

After it is installed `gcc` will still map to the clang that came with your mac. The newly installed `gcc` will be installed at `/usr/local/bin` and be called something like `gcc-4`.

You can find the exact executable name using

`ls /usr/local/bin | grep gcc`

Hopefully 4.9 is close enough to 4.6 for your purposes.